# Item 3 in [More Effective C++] seems not valid, by my test

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism

Item3:Item 3:  Never treat arrays polymorphically

It talks about that when dealing with object arrays, pointer arithmetic will calculate by the type of the pointer, not taking polymorphism/inheritance into account, so the result will be some random values, but I did a test against VC/GCC

```
struct B{
    int i = 2;
    virtual ~B(){ cout << "B dtor\n"; }
};
struct D :B{
    int j = 3;
    int k = 4;
    int l = 5;
    ~D(){ cout << "D dtor\n"; }
};
void f(B* pb,size_t s)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i)
        cout << pb->i << endl;
}
int main()
{
    B* pb = new D;
    delete pb;
    B* p2 = new D[2];
    f(p2,2);
    D buf[2];
    f(buf, 2);
    delete[] p2;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect, because a "virtual" leads to a pointer to vtable, sizeof(B) should be 8 and sizeof(D) should be 16. So in function f, visiting B[1].i is in fact D[0].k, so I expect the program to output

```
2,4,2,4
```

But VC compiles and runs this program, and outputs:

```
2,2,2,2
```

Seems VC has the magic to let "f" know it's input array is de-factor "D" type?
I also tried GCC, it also prints "2,2,2,2" but crashes when "delete[] p2".

Why this is not my expectation? And why GCC's result will even crash?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `cout << pb->i << endl;` you're just printing out the 1st element every time.

Comment: Please do not edit the question in that way - The answer below now does not make any sense. I have rolledback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should print  `cout << pb[i].i<< endl` instead of `cout << pb->i << endl;`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct B {
    int i = 2;
    virtual ~B() { cout << "B dtor\n"; }
};
struct D : B {
    int j = 3;
    int k = 4;
    int l = 5;
    ~D() { cout << "D dtor\n"; }
};
void f(B* pb, size_t s)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i)
        cout << pb[i].i<< endl;
}
int main()
{
    std :: cout << sizeof(B);
    std::cout << sizeof(D);
    B* pb = new D;
    delete pb;
    B* p2 = new D[2];
    f(p2, 2);
    D buf[2];
    f(buf, 2);
    delete[] p2;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code that give you the desired behavior. As a remark the `sizeof(B)` is 8 indeed but the `sizeof(D)` is 20 because D includes the 3 integers ( 12 bytes), the i integer from the base class (4 bytes) and the pointer from the virtual destructor (4 bytes)

Comment: Good spot, but this program you provides, GCC compile and run, still crashes. Why it crash?

Comment: @HindForsum probable because of the last `delete[] p2` line.The VC 2015 compiles and run fine.Try to remove this line.

Comment: Remove this line indicates memory leak, I wonder why my delete[] will lead to crash, I cannot use delete[] for polymorphism?

Comment: In VS 2015 the destructors are called correctly.`delete[]` calls the `delete` for the entire array so it should'not  be any problem.I wonder if there is something wrong with the  the implementation of  `delete[]` operator g++ ?

Comment: The crash might be because you're accessing past the end of the `D[2]` arrays, rather than anything to do with the `delete[]`.  You could add a `std::cerr << "about to delete[]...\n";` to confirm.

Comment: I think I only accessed D[0] in out analysis, never have chance to access beyond D[2]. But why delete crashes?